# swipe transition changepage jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, swipe-gesture

I have a problem with jQueryMobile, i search for answer many hours and nothing works :(

I have power by making a swipe left or right to move the next or previous item.

The above code works fine but after a while it becomes insane.

I'm on "Section A", I swipe right and I "Section B", I swipe left I return to "A", then I swipe right again and I go to "C"
and once on "C" if I swipe again is the carousel that connects

I pass from page C to A, then I go back to B returns C etc ...
and after a decade of change, it stops on a page and I swipe this is more an effect totally crazy scrolling display

the next and prev are urls

in html

```
   <div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="false" class="actus-page" id="news" data-theme="a" data-next="http://wip17.kenjidev.com/n/39409" data-prev="http://wip17.kenjidev.com/n/39423" data-title="La vitalité de la traduction, levier décisif de la diversité éditoriale">
```

if I put the line loadpage, this charge has an infinite ajax pages (there are over 50 000 items ..)

and js

```
  $( document ).on( "pageinit", "[data-role='page'].actus-page", function() {
    var page = "#" + $( this ).attr( "id" ),
        next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" ),
        prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );

    if ( next ) {
        //$.mobile.loadPage( next + ".htm" );
        $( document ).on( "swipeleft", page, function() {
            console.log(next +' : ' + page + ' : ' + prev );
            $.mobile.changePage( next  , {transition: "slide"});
        });
    }
    if ( prev ) {
        $( document ).on( "swiperight", page, function() {
            console.log(prev +' : ' + page + ' : ' + next );
            $.mobile.changePage( prev, { transition: "slide" , reverse: true } );
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for help

---

**Edit :  solved**

Thanks Omar for your help

finnally here code solve all problems:

```
 $( document ).on( "pageinit", ".actus-page", function() {
var 
    $page = $(this),
    page = "#" + $page.attr( "id" ), 
    next = $page.jqmData( "next" ), 
    prev = $page.jqmData( "prev" ); 

if ( next ) {  
    $page.on( "swipeleft", function() { 
        $.mobile.changePage( next , {transition: "slide"}); 
    }); 
} 

if ( prev ) { 
    $page.on( "swiperight", function() { 
        $.mobile.changePage( prev, { transition: "slide" , reverse: true} ); 
    }); 
}});
```

Comment: you have an error in fonction.js line 24. corrent syntax is `$(document).off('swipeleft swiperight').on('swipeleft swiperight', function(event) {` mind the missing `(event) {`

Comment: it looks like your previous code O_o .. anyway, glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each page has an ID, use the below code to navigate between pages in the DOM dynamically.

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
 if(event.type == 'swiperight') {
  var prevpage = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prev('div[data-role="page"]')[0].id;
  $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
   transition: 'slide',
   reverse: true
  });
 }

 if(event.type == 'swipeleft') {
  var nextpage = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.next('div[data-role="page"]')[0].id;
  $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {
   transition: 'slide',
   reverse: false
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: thank you I try but it does not work

here is what does not work:
I have one ID per page. I called lorque changePage I called a php script that generates the template me seeking the id in the database (or cache), create the template and sent to the browser.
So in the page, I only have one <div data-role = "page" id = "news_XXX" to not load all the news every time. I do not explain myself well in the outcome.

If I put several div data-role = "page" in the html page, it works with prev but not next, I TypeError: can not read property 'id' of undefined

thanks

Comment: @user2249727 in your code add `reloadPage: true` to `$.mobile.chagePage` to force reload of the page, since you have `dom-cache` set to false.

Comment: Have you check if swipe is being fired twice? @user2249727 this could be the problem. also try it without `$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 50;
    $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 30; 
    $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold = 40; 
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false`

Comment: @user2249727 `$(document).off('swipeleft swiperight').on('swipeleft swiperight', function ()` try this to make sure swipe doesn't fire twice.

Comment: i comemnt four lines and add document.off but after 2 -3 swipe, swipe not working anymore, very strange but it work a litte better ;)